Writing a repository for a class that has OneToOne primary key field
I have two model classes in a Spring web application:
User.java:
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String email;
}


Client.java:
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@IdClass(User.class)
public class Client {

    @Id
    private String username;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")
    private User user;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private String address;

}


And a repository ClientRepository:
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, User> {}

When I run the application I get the following error:
This class [class com.example.auction.models.Client] does not define an IdClass
What is the reason for that? I used the IdClass annotation in Client class.

Do you really want the username to be your @Id? Remember, that primary keys should NOT be changed! Hence the usernames cannot be changed. Re-think your concept.

The error occurs because you don't respect the contract as it has been defined in documentation of how to use the @IdClass.

The names of the fields or properties in the primary key class and the
primary key fields or properties of the entity must correspond and
their types must be the same.

@IdClass(User.class)
public class Client {

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "username")
    private User user;

You don't use the same name and type for the id field as it has been defined in the class User. You have to use with @Id one specific field of User.class, not the User.class it self.
So the correct way would have been:
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@IdClass(User.class)
public class Client {

    @Id
    private String username;

    ...
}

With the use of @IdClass you have access directly to the composite primary key fields.
The @OneToOne relationship between a Client and a User has to be defined separately.
E.g.
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @IdClass(User.class)
    public class Client {
    
        @Id
        private String username;
        
        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")
        private User user;
    
        ...
    }


check edited question. I now get: Entity 'com.example.auction.models.Client' has an '@IdClass' with properties 'password', 'email' which do not match properties of the entity class.
When I add those fields to Client they all become primary keys.
